# How to run SSIS package with password in Windows Scheduler?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, windows-task-scheduler, dtexec

I have an SSIS package that has the `ProtectionLevel=EncryptSensitiveWithPassword` and would like to run this project `.dtsx` file from the Windows Task Scheduler (on MS Windows Server 2012). In the task scheduler, trying to run...

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"
```

with added args

```sh
/Decrypt <mypassword> C:/path/to/my/Visual Studio/package.dtsx
```

(not sure if this is the right syntax for adding them)

[image]

Looking at some [community docs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/77d566e6-24c3-471f-8776-d251f55e069e/execute-package-task-password-issue?forum=sqlintegrationservices), I think would need to use the `/Decrypt <mypassword>` arg, but not quite sure *how* to "use" it. After manually running the scheduled task, it appears to have no effect (eg. the MSSQL tables that the SSIS package is supposed to write to is still empty (despite the SSIS project running fine when running in Visual Studio)).

Can anyone with more experience with Windows know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to add /FILE or /F before the dtsx package file path:

```
dtexec /FILE "C:\path\to\my\Visual Studio\package.dtsx" /DECRYPT password
```

**References**

- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017)
- [The DTEXEC /DECRYPT option](http://thomaskrehbiel.com/post/1260-the_dtexec_decrypt_option/)